# Counting an int in a vector from a number stored in a set?

Tags: c++, vector, count, iterator, set

So, this may sound confusing, but I'm writing a prime factorization method, and I'm trying to find out how many times a certain number appears in a vector. To do that, I made a set that holds the unique values (so I know which numbers/how many numbers to count in the vector), but I'm having trouble putting it together.

I know that I can count through the vector using an iterator, but I don't know how to say, "hey, check for the number at position one in the set." I looked through resources, but they only use find, and I'm assuming that I don't know what the numbers in the `vector<int>` are, or where the index is where the number changes (if it does).

I figured I could iterate through the set, but doing that gives me the counts for all of the numbers, which I'm storing in another vector. I mean, I suppose I could just divide the count vector in half, but that's kind of jerry-rigging it, and I'd rather just code it right the first time than have to come up with tricks to get the results I want, because I did the latter in a previous method I wrote and it only worked sometimes.

Comment: Instead of a set I would use a std::map of number to count, and just keep building it while iterating the vector.

Comment: why do you use vector in the first place? do you need to keep the inserting order?
if the order of the insertion is not important, use a map<int> that will hold a counter for each number, the couter will be the value (that you will increase instead of inserting to the vector) and the number will be the key.

Comment: @idanuda I really don't need to, but it was the first way I thought of storing all of the factors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, if this is the case, you don't need a `Set` for the counting, just iterate over the map -

```
void SomeClass::Insert (int newNumber)
{
    if (m_map.count (newNumber) > 0)
    {
        m_map[newNumber]++;
    }
    else 
    {
        m_map[newNumber] = 1;
    }
}

void SomeClass::Count ()
{
    for (map<int,int>::iterator it=m_map.begin(); it!=m_map.end(); ++it)
    {
        std::cout << "the number: "<< it->first << " apears " << it->second << "times" <<'\n';
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you just explain to me what it->first and it->second do? Because I need to use these numbers for another purpose, and I'd like to know what exactly is going on (I've never worked with maps or iterators prior to today).

Comment: `it` hold a pair of values, the key and the value of the key in the map.
`it->first` is the key and `it->second` is the value of the key.
in your case the values of the map will hold the counter for each number, and the keys will be the numbers, each `pair` a key and value will hold a number and its counter.
review this for the usage of c++ maps - [link] (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/)